# Null pointer exception on recognizer.allocate

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4

I have a doubt in sphinx4-5 prealpha release. I'm not able to use class Recognizer, earlier in sphinx4 we were able to use like this: `Recognizer recognizer = new Recognizer(); 
recognizer.allocate();`
But the same piece of code in sphinx4-5 prealpha gives me nullPointerException at recognizer.allocate();

Code Snippet:

```
`Configuration cn = new Configuration();
cn.setAcousticModelPath(Acoustic_Model);
cn.setDictionaryPath(Dictionary_Path);
cn.setLanguageModelPath(LANGUAGE_MODEL);
Recognizer recognizer = new Recognizer();
recognizer.allocate();`
```

StackTrace: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.allocate(Recognizer.java:164) at edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.dialog.SampleSphinx.main(SampleSphinx.java:26) Exception is at recognizer.allocate`

In sphinx4 we use to allocate resource from configuration like this:
`Configuration configuration = new Configuration();                                                                               Recognizer recognizer = new Recognizer();                                                    recognizer = (Recognizer) configuration.lookup();`

but now as we know we use api in sphinx4-5 prealpha and we dont have lookup() in Configuration class. So how we will load JSGFGrammar and Recognizer in sphinx4-5 pre alpha. Hope I'm clear with my doubts please help in this @nikolay Thank You in advance.

Comment: You did not provide enough information to get help on this issue - neither code not exception stacktrace.

Comment: You need to edit the question with properly formatted code and full stacktrace

Comment: I have edited question please look into it. Thank You.

Comment: It is not properly formatted yet, and stacktrace is not complete

Comment: Hello Sir. the stacktrace is complete, that is what I got while building it. thanks